# Block Access on Android and Apple Tablets

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ipad, mobile

I have the following project for a client:

I need to completely revoke access to the Android system, showing a Login screen that will be used to regain access to the system.

In detail:

## Workflow

A timer has to be turned on. After this timer has reached a certain amount of time, say, 1h, the Android will be automatically blocked, only showing a Login screen and NOTHING else. From this login screen, the user will be able to input a passcode to regain access to the system for a certain amount of time, after which, the access will be revoked again, starting the process all over.

Basically it's like this:

[ 1 ] ---> [ 2 ] ---> [ 3 ]
^ |
|----------------------|

1 - Timer is set.
2 - Timer has ended. Device was locked.
3 - Passcode was entered. Device was unlocked, setting a new timer (1).

## Plus

I must be able to remotely block and unblock this Android tablet by sending it a message online. 
As for the pass codes, I also need a way to generate pass codes and have the Android tablets verify the valid codes to give back access to the tablet.

PS.: Can I do the same thing with apple tablets (ipad, 1,2 and 3)? If yes, how? Must use jailbreak? What's the easiest way?

Comment: *"CAN I DO*"  Can you stop SHOUTING?  BTW - this app. sounds horrid.  Why would I want to install such an app. on any device I control?  What feature does it provide to me?

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's likely this woudl be installed on company-supplied android devices holding hot IP - I guess this is supposed to prevent unauthorised people from accessing it.  Of course, nothing stops them simply plugging the device into a USB cable :3

Comment: Too much shouting = less will to read

Comment: *"it's likely"*  Thanks, you're probably right.  But I'm not interested in speculation, I want an answer from the OP.

Comment: I do only see question-marks on the iPad related part. The rest of your posting seems to be a copy of the requirements you got. Does that mean you want us to do your work?

Comment: @mcfinnigan is right and it´s exactly what I want. I need to develop this for Android Tablets and iPad Tablets. But I don´t know if in Apple Tablets a jailbreak will be necessary! And the USB cable issue in Android Tablets is a problem too.

Answer (score 0):

yes i guess you can do this using [this package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/package-summary.html).gives you more privileges eg.you caneven block market and stuff.

sorry but i have not had chance to use it to guide you further and have no idea for Iphone.